# Having count on result of Group_Concat

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have applied the Group_Concat on my query and the results are displayed just fine. Below is my query,

```
SELECT tblUserGroup.GroupID, GROUP_CONCAT(tblUserGroup.UserId) AS UserIds FROM     
tblGroup 
INNER JOIN tblUserGroup ON tblGroup.GroupID = tblUserGroup.GroupID 
GROUP BY tblUserGroup.GroupID
ORDER BY (UserIds)
```

NOW the ouput is something like this.

```
GroupID     UserIds
   1           1,2
   2           1,4
   3           1,2,3
   4           1,2
   5           1,2
   6           1,2,3
```

I have read different questions on GROUP_CONCAT and COUNT but I want to apply count not on UserId rather I want to apply count on theGROUP_CONCAT such as "1,2".

What I want is to modify this query such that it only display those records which occurs more then one time. For example just 1,2 and 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use subquery? It would be something like:

```
SELECT Sub.UserIds, COUNT(*) as Qt
FROM (
    SELECT tblUserGroup.GroupID, GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(tblUserGroup.UserId, CHAR(20)) SEPARATOR ',') AS UserIds, count(*) FROM     
    tblGroup 
    INNER JOIN tblUserGroup ON tblGroup.GroupID = tblUserGroup.GroupID 
    GROUP BY tblUserGroup.GroupID HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
) AS Sub
GROUP BY Sub.UserIds
```

Comment: I could not use your query exact as it is but it is pretty close to my requirement. I have modified it and it worked. Thank you guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use count and use below query (I could not test it):

```
SELECT tblUserGroup.GroupID, GROUP_CONCAT(tblUserGroup.UserId) AS UserIds, count(*) FROM     
tblGroup 
INNER JOIN tblUserGroup ON tblGroup.GroupID = tblUserGroup.GroupID 
GROUP BY tblUserGroup.GroupID HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY (UserIds)
```

Comment: Count(*) here is giving me the count of items. For example  for (1,2) count is 2. For (1,2,3) count is 3 and for (1,2,3,4) count is 4. What I want is the occurrence of (1,2)